# Open file in OS X

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

In Delphi, I would like to open a file in OS X. My approach is as follows:

```
const
  Filename = 'test.bmp';

procedure SaveAndOpen;
begin
  Chart.SaveToBitmapFile(Filename);
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  ShellExecute(0, 'open', Filename, '', '', SW_Normal);
  {$ELSE}
  _System(Filename);
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

But nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using  `_System(PAnsiChar('open ' + Filename));`

Comment: Thank you, it works ! :-) An additional question, but not important: Is there a way to use Unicode filenames?

Comment: Surely there's something better than `_System`? For Unicode, wouldn't you pass UTF-8 data?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I do not know if the POSIX standard wants UTF8 inside _system() . I think there is an OS X API for opening files, but I didn't find a good documentation.

Comment: @RRUZ Are you sure about system and ANSI? After all ANSI is peculiarly Windows. On typical modern *nix systems, `char*` will be UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, you are right the `system` function supports UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This article from Embarcadero's Malcolm Groves covers this topic: [Opening files and URLs in default applications in OS X](http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=887).

In summary, all you need is this:

```
uses
  Macapi.Appkit,       // for NSWorkspace
  Macapi.Foundation;   // for NSSTR
....
var
  Workspace: NSWorkspace; // interface, no need for explicit destruction
....
Workspace := TNSWorkspace.Create;
Workspace.openFile(NSSTR(FileName));
```

For sake of completeness, should you wish to open a URL rather than a file, then you call `openURL` instead:

```
Workspace.openURL(NSSTR(URL));
```

Regarding your Windows code, I would recommend not using `ShellExecute`. That function does not have reasonable error reporting. Use `ShellExecuteEx` in its place.

And finally, you should probably abstract this functionality away so that it can be re-used by other parts of your program. You want to write that `IFDEF` as few times as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have applied all the imporvement suggestions and created a function which should cover all cases. http://pastebin.com/TyMTMStr (I use it for OpenSource, so it is important for me that the code is perfect and universal). If you have some more improvement suggestions, please let me know. I was a bit confused about `ExtractFilePath` and `ExtractFileDir`, and I wonder what happens when `_system()` gets an UTF8 string which contains a NUL character (which would not work because of PAnsiChar). Why did the POSIX specification allow UTF8 when UTF8 can include NUL?

Comment: UTF-8 doesn't encode any characters with a zero byte, apart from `nul`. I think you are confused about something there. You have to remove that call to `CoInitializeEx`. Not only does it leak fail to call `CoUninitialize`, but a function like this cannot be in charge of initializing COM. The caller has to take control of that. `Info := Default(TShellExecuteInfo)` is the way to default init nowadays. `ExtractFileDir` and `ExtractFilePath`, either is fine. Including `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` means you leak the process handle. Remove that flag.

Comment: Thank you! I did understand all the issues and fixed them.

Comment: Can you show me another pastebin so I can check one more time.

Comment: Yeah, that looks solid to me. Regarding `Default`, if you have to support versions that don't have `Default` then it's not worth trying to shoe-horn it in. And if you zero-init the record, there's no need for further zero-init. With that in mind, I'd do it like this, a little simpler: http://pastebin.com/CDBGLt0Z  You might also wonder about not passing the `open` verb in the Windows version and letting the system choose the default verb.

Answer (score 3):

You must add the `open` verb like so

```
_System(PAnsiChar('open ' + Filename));
```

Comment: This is not a good approach in my view. I don't think we should be encouraging the use of `system` these days -1

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I'm only answering the question. I don't see any problems in use Posix functions over Cocoa methods, just depends of what your needs.

Comment: The problems with `system` have been discussed many times. There is coverage in the official documentation. Leaving that to one side, the inability of your code to handle Unicode is less than ideal. Do you think that `_System` is preferable to the Cocoa alternative?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I'm not recommending Posix over Cocoa, only `answering the question` why the code doesn't works, Also is not a `inability` of my code don't handle unicode , this is a limitation of the system method.

Comment: OK. I just think that it is an opportunity missed just to answer the question at face value. As it stands, unless anybody speaks up as I did, future visitors may well think that `_System` is the way to go. And all the voting here serves to re-inforce that. On the face of it, the voting here makes it seem that the Cocoa version is a bad idea. Perhaps it is. Perhaps I've got this completely wrong. Oh well.